# How to use redis dockerhub as a service in Gitlab CI .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: redis, gitlab-ci

My **.gitlab-ci.yml** is this:

```
image: "python:3.5"

services:
  - redis:4.0.2
  - mongo:3.4.10

stages:
  - checkEverythingRuns

checkEverythingRuns:
  stage: checkEverythingRuns 
  script: 
    - "python --version"
    - "pip --version"
    - "redis-server -v"
    - "mongod --version"
```

The redis image downloads correctly:

```
Using docker image redis:4.0.2 ID=sha256:blablabla
```

But it throws the next error:

```
$ redis-server -v
/bin/bash: line 14: redis-server: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The `redis-server` command is not found on the image you are running your job in: `python:3.5`. The `redis` server is a container auto-linked to your job-container, python:3.5.

You could install `redis-tools` with `apt-get install redis-tools` and then run:

`redis-cli -h redis ping`

`redis` is the [default hostname](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services) your service gets, if you want to change it take a look here to [specify a service alias](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#available-settings-for-services).